# Sintaxis orden en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo un pequeño problema con el orden de una base de datos donde uso ORDER BY ASC y me muestras los resultados al reves.

Les comparto el codigo y les dejo imagen:

```
select 'Seleccione...' as analisis union (SELECT DISTINCT analisis 
FROM ensayos  WHERE laboratorio LIKE '%LET-SA%'  
AND  matriz LIKE '%Agua de Mar%' 
ORDER BY analisis ASC) 
union select 'Otros' as analisis union select 'No Aplica' as analisis
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

siendo que deberia verse así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tampoco están al revés, simplemente no están ordenados ni en un sentido ni en otro... Yo te preguntaría, ¿por qué usas tantos `UNION`?  ¿Qué resultado final quieres?  Si escribes sólo esta consulta: `SELECT DISTINCT analisis 
FROM ensayos  WHERE laboratorio LIKE '%LET-SA%'  
AND  matriz LIKE '%Agua de Mar%' 
ORDER BY analisis ASC`  ¿te los ordena bien?

Comment: los union los coloco porque esa consulta sale a un ComboBox que necesita dichas opciones... se que se podria poner en el mismo combobox, pero uso un RemoveAllItems antes de cargar la consulta

Comment: Yo no haría así. Al hacer eso tú tratas a la BD como si fuera un lenguaje de programación. ¿Por qué no consultas los datos de la forma más simple posible y luego armas el combobox por progamación en el lenguaje que sea?. Así distribuyes funciones. Una BD es potente para almacenar datos, un lenguaje de programación es potente para leer esos datos y organizarlos, darles formato, etc. No pretendas hacer todo en la BD cuando de todos modos tendrás que manejar los datos en lenguaje de programación.

Comment: esa consulta SELECT DISTINCT analisis FROM ensayos WHERE laboratorio LIKE '%LET-SA%' AND matriz LIKE '%Agua de Mar%' ORDER BY analisis ASC si los ordena bien... no hay problema con esa consulta

Comment: El `ORDER` debe ser aplicado a todo el conjunto de datos

Comment: Pues eso, escribe la consulta solamente así y luego maneja los resultados por programación. No entiendo lo que dices del `RemoveAllItems` pero no tiene nada que ver. Puedes guardar los resultados en una variable aparte y mostrarlos donde, como y cuando quieras.

Comment: Efectivamente tuve que hacerlo de manera separada, solo extraer el dato sin union y trabajar sobre codigo, Muchas gracias estimado

Comment: Me alegro. La base de datos te lo agradecerá y tendrás una aplicación mejor optimizada. Saludos.